# Water4Advance far view seems stale and plain

Tags: unity

Hi How can I remove far clipping in Water4Advance so that it matches near view like following img?

Currently far view water seems plaine with no wave n bumps at all.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be due to Mip Maps as it blurs out the texture farther away from the camera. In 3D computer graphics, mipmaps are pre-calculated, optimized sequences of textures, each of which is a progressively lower resolution representation of the same image. They are intended to increase rendering speed and reduce aliasing artifacts.

Try to switch off "Generte MipMaps" option for all the texture / bump maps (in the import settings) which are used by the water.

Comment: You sir, Legend

Comment: Lol , you are welcome durvesh :)